# what are these default channels in a pubnub channelgroup?

Tags: publish-subscribe, pubnub

I can see the following 4 channels by default in my channelGroup(satya-channelGroup):

> 1. private.admin
> 2. private.admin-meta
> 3. private.satya
> 4. private.satya-meta

***What are these channels??***

when I delete my **channelGroup**, these default channels also got deleted?
Is this behavior okay?

Comment: I got it. thanks!!

Comment: Thanks. I moved my comment to official answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## Channel Groups: adding & deleting channels

There is no such thing as a default channel in a channel group. They only get there because they get explicitly added to the channel group by your code (or someone else's code that has your keys).

Deleting a channel group just means you are getting rid of a the thing that kept a list of those channels. The channels can still exist if others are subscribed to them or they are in another channel group.